Unable to see adsense ads in content in Nextjs 14 app
I have a Nextjs app [portfolio][1]
In this app I cannot the ads displayed in the content, I can see the ads only when navigating the pages.
While navigating it just pop and I close thats all.
I cannot see the ads in content in the pages.
I have enable auto ads and also added by ad unit
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function ManualAds() {
    const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsClient(true);

        if (!isClient) return;

        try {
            (window as any).adsbygoogle = ((window as any).adsbygoogle || []).push(
                {}
            );
        } catch (error) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.error(error);
        }
    }, [isClient]);
    return (
        <ins
            className="adsbygoogle"
            style={{ display: "block" }}
            data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxx"
            data-ad-slot="xxx"
            data-ad-format="auto"
            data-full-width-responsive="true"
        />
    );
}

I have used this component in several places, in homepage I cannot see any ads there.
Still only while navigating
How do I enable to display ads there
